# Delphi: PopUpMenu

Tags: delphi, popupmenu

There is a list View + a PopUpMenu. I need that the PopUpMenu appears when items are present. The menu must not appears when 0 items.

Is this approximate code appropriate (can be used as a basis)?

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var P: TPoint;
begin
  P:=GetClientOrigin;
  if Button = mbRight then
     PopupMenu1.Popup(X+P.X+StringGrid1.Left, Y+P.Y+StringGrid1.Top);
end;
```

Are there other ways?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't do anything on a mouse event because the popup menu can be invoked from the keyboard.

The best way to do this, in my view, is to handle the `OnPopup` event. If you want the menu not to appear call `Abort`.

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SomeCondition then
    Abort;
end;
```